# How to access local image when setting the background image in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, image

My goal is to set the background image from a local image on my computer.

I have two lines of code, one that works and one that doesn't:
(the local one does not work)

```
                _html.style.backgroundImage = 'url("urlsourceblahblahblah")';
                _html.style.backgroundImage = 'url("/~/Content/images/Image1.jpg")';
```

When I try running the second one (the local one), this is the error that I get:

GET http://localhost:23433/~/Content/images/Image1.jpg 404 (Not Found)

I can verify that the image path is correct, even if I put the image file in the same directory to make things simple. I know from documentation that the backgroundImage property in JS requires url(). Is there any reason why this wouldn't work?

Comment: if you put http://localhost:23433/~/Content/images/Image1.jpg in your browser, what do you get?  I assume having the /~/ is not correct.

Comment: The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Comment: What folder is the project in if you are at http://localhost:23433/ ?

Comment: it looks like you are using asp.net. in this case you need to transform the relative url `~` before passing it back to the client.

Comment: otherwise, using `~` isn't typically used in a url, so you'll need to find the correct path to the image.

Answer (score 2):

This is a tricky one... I can think of some problems this can have:

1. The server doesn't know what ~ refers to (are you running windows?)
2. The user running the server is not the same as the one you are logged in as. (~ stands for home directory, and when server evaluates it'll lead to user running the server home directory).
3. The server is configured to ignore every request which is above it's www / html / localweb folder. (Altough in this case it would be weird to reply with a 404, a 403 would make more sense)

By the way, this is only possible if the server and the client are on the same machine. I don't know why you want it, but if you pretend to upload a website and have its background set to some field on the client machine, then simply forget about it.

Answer (score 0):

The `~` abbreviation for your home directory is not recognized by the browser.  However, expanding it will only help if the image is in a directory that is being served on local host.  I don't know what you are using for a web server, but you'll need to find out what directory it is expecting to serve as its root

Answer (score 0):

You can't refer to an image from the users machine. The browser does not have access to the users file system, otherwise, any website you visit would be able to access your "Pictures" folder for example.

The image you use needs to be in your website directory or another public url. If you need to use a picture from the users machine, then you should do so with a file uploader.